# If one binary tree is the subtree of another tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, subtree

I wrote this function to check if `n2` is the subtree of `n1`. I use recursion, but when I tested it using two trees, it showed me the wrong answer (expected `true`, but it actually returned `false`).

I struggled for a while but still cannot say what's wrong.

```
private Boolean isSubTree(node n1, node n2){
    if(n1 == null)
        return false;
    if(n2 == null)
        return true;
    if(n1.data == n2.data){
        return isSubTree(n1.left,n2.left) && isSubTree(n2.right,n2.right);
    }
    else
        return isSubTree(n1.left, n2) || isSubTree(n1.right, n2);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Yes, agree with you. Thanks for reminding me about this.

Comment: What this code actually does is to determine whether it is possible to create the second tree from the first tree by removing branches from it. However it permits the branches to be removed from within the tree, which means that it's not a true subtree.

Answer (score 0):

Your edge cases are incorrect. In particular, when both `n1` and `n2` are null then that counts as a matching subtree, but if only one is null, then that counts as a mismatch.

Comment: n1 is the larger tree, n2 is the subtree needed to be check. When n2 is null, it could be treated as a subtree of n1. Right?

Comment: Yes, I misread the question and this answer is wrong. If I think of another answer I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to check n2's parent to see whether or not it's n1. if not, continue all the way until you find it; in which case you return true. the alternate is that all parents up to and including the root are not n1; in which case you return false. In other words, work your way up instead of checking all possible children and their children etc. of n1 to reach n2.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases to consider.

1. If the subtree has to be one of the nodes of the original tree then you can scan the tree for the matching subtree node.
2. If the subtree only has to have equal values, then you need to write a recursive tree equality function and apply it to all the leaves of the original tree in a second recursive function.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I like your answer very much. Actually, what I mean is the second case in your response- just check if two trees have equal values. But what i cannot understand is that: why my function is not enough to use as an equality function(I've already check n1.data == n2.data). Hope for your response.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with nabau ... its better to check weather **n2's  and n1's root node is same if we have data for parent in node**

else  we can check n2's root with node of every node in n1's

in java we can compare two objects are same or not
**forEach all node in n1 equals root of n2**  if any is node is equal they are same